# Parsing a date that can be in several formats in python

Tags: python, ruby, parsing, datetime

I would like to parse a date that can come in several formats, that I know beforehand. If I could not parse, I return nil. In ruby, I do like this:

```
DATE_FORMATS = ['%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%Y', '%Y/%m/%d']

def parse_or_nil(date_str)
    parsed_date = nil
    DATE_FORMATS.each do |f|
        parsed_date ||= DateTime.strptime(date_str, f) rescue nil
    end
    parsed_date
end
```

This is concise and works. How can I do the same thing in Python?

Comment: You are looking for [strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Maybe better: `DATE_FORMATS.any?`, breaking early.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `try/except` to catch the `ValueError` that would occur when trying to use a non-matching format. As @Bakuriu mentions, you can stop the iteration when you find a match to avoid the unnecessary parsing, and then define your behavior when `my_date` doesn't get defined because not matching formats are found:

You can use `try/except` to catch the `ValueError` that would occur when trying to use a non-matching format:

```
from datetime import datetime

DATE_FORMATS = ['%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%Y', '%Y/%m/%d']
test_date = '2012/1/1 12:32:11'

for date_format in DATE_FORMATS:
    try:
        my_date = datetime.strptime(test_date, date_format)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
      break
else:
  my_date = None

print my_date # 2012-01-01 12:32:11
print type(my_date) # <type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Comment: I'd use a break even if not necessary. It avoids unnecessary parsing and exception handling. Also, this fails to define `my_date` when no format is correct. Adding a break you can use python's `else` clause to the `for` to define `my_date` as `None`.

Comment: @Bakuriu Great point, will amend (last time I write something before heading to lunch :) ).

Comment: Great answer, not concise enough, but if I cannot find anything better, I will accept this.

Comment: You can do `my_date = datetime.strptime(...); break` instead of using the `else` with the `try` statement. Anyway there isn't anything more concise. `strptime` raises a `ValueError` for invalid formats and you must handle it. An alternative to the `try` statement would be to use a `with` statement and let a context manager handle the exception, but it would require more code(even though later you could re-use the manager in other situations).

Answer (score 19):

I would just try [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil). It can recognize most of the formats:

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse(string)
```

if you end up using datetime.strptime as suggested @RocketDonkey:

```
from datetime import datetime

def func(s,flist):
    for f in flist:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(s,f)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Comment: +1, why do you have to make me look bad? :) Much better option.

Comment: Almost! The problem is, this makes wrong assumptions around m/d/y or d/m/y.

Comment: @LuísGuilherme -- can you give an example?

Comment: @LuísGuilherme I would actually suggest un-accepting my answer and accepting this one - the first suggestion is much more concise and the second is likely what you need anyway :)

Comment: @RocketDonkey -- it's like chistmas all over again :)

Comment: Haha, I actually never knew about `parser` in `dateutil`, so I thank you for your present.

Comment: `from dateutil import parser
parser.parse("2018:12:08 16:48:19")
#gives 2021-02-24(current date)`

wired behavior

Answer (score 3):

After your tip, RocketDonkey, and the one from Bakuriu, I could write a shorter version. Any problem with it?

```
def parse_or_none(date):
    for date_format in DATE_FORMATS:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(date, date_format)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return None
```

Comment: Looks good to me - you can take out the `return None` as the function will return `None` by default if it gets to that point without returning.

Comment: +1 That seems pretty concise, I was writing it down at the same time, I guess that's the obvious way to do it :)

Comment: I actually like the final `return None` because, it's true that it is not necessary but it states explicitly that returning `None` if no format is found is part of the function interface and not just a negligence/bug.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying root's answer to handle m/d/y:

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse(string, dayfirst=False)
```

There's also a yearfirst option, to prefer y/m/d.