# How to deal with multiple date string formats in a python series

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, pandas

I have a csv file which I am trying to complete operations on. I have created a dataframe with one column titled "start_date" which has the date of warranty start. The problem I have encountered is that the format of the date is not consistent. I would like to know the number of days passed from today's calendar date and the date warranty started for this product.

Two examples of the entries in this start_date series:

```
9/11/15
9/11/15 0:00
```

How can I identify each of these formats and treat them accordingly?

Comment: Please show your code. Explain what exactly in your code is not working. Post full error messages that you are receiving from your stack trace. Also, read this: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately you just have to try each format it might be. If you give an example format, [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) will attempt to parse it for you as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245029/parsing-a-date-that-can-be-in-several-formats-in-python).

The code will end up looking like:

```
import datetime    

POSSIBLE_DATE_FORMATS = ['%m/%d/%Y', '%Y/%m/%d', etc...] # all the formats the date might be in

for date_format in POSSIBLE_DATE_FORMATS :
    try:
        parsed_date = datetime.strptime(raw_string_date, date_format) # try to get the date
        break # if correct format, don't test any other formats
    except ValueError:
        pass # if incorrect format, keep trying other formats
```

Comment: Since `format` is a reserved name, I would use a different variable name.

I would go for `POSSIBLE_DATE_FORMATS` and `date_format`.

Comment: No problem ;) . By the way, you missed changing the `POSSIBLE_FORMATS` variable name

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options really. I'm not entirely sure what happens when you try to directly load the file with a 'pd.read_csv' but as suggested above you can define a set of format strings that you can try to use to parse the data.

One other option would be to read the date column in as a string and then parse it yourself. If you want the column to be like 'YYYY-MM-DD' then parse the string to have just that data and then save it back, something like.

```
import pandas as prandas
import datetime

df = prandas.read_csv('supa_kewl_data.dis_fmt_rox', dtype={'start_date': str})

print df.head()
# we are interested in start_date

date_strs = df['start_date'].values
#YYYY-MM-DD
#012345678910
filter_date_strs = [x[0:10] for x in date_strs]
df['filter_date_strs] = filter_date_strs

# sometimes i've gotten complained at by pandas for doing this
# try doing df.loc[:,'filter_date_strs'] = filter_date_strs
# if you get some warning thing

# if you want you can convert back to date time using a 
dobjs = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d') for x in filter_date_strs]
df['dobj_start_date'] = dobjs

df.to_csv('even_better_data.csv', index=False)
```

Hopefully this helps! Pandas documentation is sketchy sometimes, looking at the doc in 0.16.2 for read_csv() is intimidating... http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html
The library itself is stellar!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but this is what I do when I'm working with Pandas on excel files and want the date format to be 'mm/dd/yyyy' or some other.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter', datetime_format='mm/dd/yyyy')
df.to_excel(writer, sheetname)
```

Maybe it'll work with:
    df.to_csv