# pandas handle column with different date time formats gracefully

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas

I have a column with a birthdate. Some are N.A, some `01.01.2016` but some contain `01.01.2016 01:01:01`
Filtering the N.A. values works fine. But handling the different date formats seems clumsy. Is it possible to have pandas handle these gracefully and e.g. for a birthdate only interpret the date and not fail?

Comment: Probably already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32854764/6614295

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pd.to_datetime()` will handle multiple formats

```
>>> ser = pd.Series(['NaT', '01.01.2016', '01.01.2016 01:01:01'])
>>> pd.to_datetime(ser)
0                   NaT
1   2016-01-01 00:00:00
2   2016-01-01 01:01:01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: yes, you might need to convert your N.A.s to `'NaT'` though