# grep content from pdf file and write it partwise into variables

Tags: linux, bash, variables, grep, filenames

Introducing myself as I'm just started to join stack overflow after searching around for some days.
I'm working on a little project with my RasPi sorting out my PDF documents with speaking filenames.

I'm going to grep with pdfgrep the companyname and the date from various documents.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set work directory
workpath=~pi/Documents/

find $workpath/ -iname '*.pdf' -print | while read FILENAME
do
        if pdfgrep -i --max-count 1 'company1' "${FILENAME}";
        then
                echo "$FILENAME";
                pdfgrep  --max-count 1 '(([0-9][0-9]{,1}\.)\s+('Januar'|'Februar'|'März'|'April'|'Mai'|'Juni'|'Juli'|'August'|'September'|'Oktober'|'November'|'Dezember')\s+([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]{1,}))' "${FILENAME}";
                echo "company1";
       elif pdfgrep -i --max-count 1 'company2' "${FILENAME}";
       then
               echo "$FILENAME";
               pdfgrep  --max-count 1 '('Datum:')\s+(([0-9][0-9]{,1}\.)([0-9][0-9]{,1}\.)([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]{1,}))'
               echo "company2";
        else
                echo "$FILENAME";
                echo "undefined document -- Error!!";
        fi
done
```

For each file I get different content as:

> ***companyname***
>
> **paper of conduct *companyname***
>
> ***companyname* and companyaddress**
>
> and more different stuff

The date comes also different

> **dd.mm.yyyy**
>
> **date:          *dd.mm.yyyy***
>
> **some text           *dd. month yyyy***
>
> _______________________**dd.month yyyy**

I'm looking for a way to write only the needed content, without text around, into variables as:

> comp=companyname
>
> datey=yyyy
>
> datem=mm        / *here I need also an idea how to translate **month** to **mm***
>
> dated=dd

result should be: **yyyymmdd-companyname.pdf**

I started with bash scripting, as this is I get pdfgrep working and I'm not quite familar with programming languages.
Maybe I did some lines in python :S

Your help will be very welcome!

cheers, bdream

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full solution but a list of hints.

Adding **option `-o`** to the `pdfgrep` command should **print only the matching part** of the line, i.e. eliminate additional text like "date:" etc.

```
pdfgrep -o --max-count 1 '(([0-9][0-9]{,1}\.)\s+('Januar'|'Februar'|'März'|'April'|'Mai'|'Juni'|'Juli'|'August'|'September'|'Oktober'|'November'|'Dezember')\s+([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]{1,}))' "${FILENAME}";
```

Since you search for specific company names in

```
if pdfgrep -i --max-count 1 'company1' "${FILENAME}";
```

etc you don't really need the output, you can use your known company name instead. You can add **option `-q` to suppress the output**

```
if pdfgrep -q -i --max-count 1 'company1' "${FILENAME}";
```

So the remaining task is to parse various date/time formats which can be done using `strptime` function available in Python or Perl or using the Python `dateutil` library. See [Parsing a date that can be in several formats in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14245029/10622916)